# How to draw a histogram of bins of the same width and different height in a certain interval?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, histogram, bins

I have an interval `0.0`..`1.0` and heights of 10 bins inside it, for example:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

How can I render a histogram of these bins with the same width using Matplotlib?

Comment: In your example, are all bins supposed to have the _same_ height? If so, it is not a good example.

Comment: @DYZ, the key problem is that Matplotlib's `pyplot.hist` function groups input values itself, but my input data is already grouped and the heights of the bins are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's clearly explained in the doc string of `hist`

> ```
> Docstring:
> Plot a histogram.
>
> Compute and draw the histogram of *x*.  The return value is a tuple
> (*n*, *bins*, *patches*) or ([*n0*, *n1*, ...], *bins*, [*patches0*,
> *patches1*, ...]) if the input contains multiple data.  See the
> documentation of the *weights* parameter to draw a histogram of
> already-binned data.
> ```

```
In [24]: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: 
    ...: w = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
    ...: n = len(w)
    ...: 
    ...: left, right = 0.0, 1.0
    ...: plt.hist(np.arange(left+d/2, right, d),
    ...:          np.arange(left, right+d/2, d),
    ...:          weights=w, rwidth=0.7)
    ...: plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the `hist` function, you could make use of the `bar` function.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
heights = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
bar_width = 0.08

plt.bar(xs, heights, bar_width)
```